# PineScript plot shape or arrow on indicator panel

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to plot a shape or arrow on an indicator panel where Study(overlay=false)?

If I have a study declared like this

```
//@version=4
study("My Custom Indicator", overlay=false)
// ... 
plotarrow(true, title="EMA Cross", colorup=color.lime, colordown=color.red, transp=50)
```

It results in this

[image]

What I want to do is have the arrows at a specific Y-value where the indicator is drawing, but its using the main price chart price for its Y-value

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this using the plotShape function

```
shouldPlot = true // this is your series of booleans where you want to plot the shape
plotshape(yValue, style=shape.circle, color = shouldPlot ? color.green : na, location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny)
```

This plots a single dot (circle) at the yValue when shouldPlot is true